# Dynamic programming - paint fence algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

There is a fence with *n* posts, each post can be painted with one of the *k* colors. You have to paint all the posts such that no more than two adjacent fence posts have the same color. Return the total number of ways you can paint the fence.

*diff* - number of combinations with different colors,
*same* - number of combinations with same colors,
*n* - number of posts,
*k* - number of colors.

For n = 1 :

```
diff = k;
same = 0;
```

For n = 2 :

```
diff = k * (k - 1);
same = k;
```

For n = 3 :

```
diff = (k + k * (k - 1)) * (k - 1);
same = k * (k - 1);
```

And the final formula is :

```
diff[i] = (diff[i - 1] + diff[i - 2]) * (k - 1);
same[i] =  diff[i - 1];
```

I understand how to find `same[i]`, but I don't understand how to find `diff[i]`. Can you explain the formula for `diff[i]`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
total[i] = diff[i] + same[i]   (definition)

diff[i] = (k - 1) * total[i-1]
        = (k - 1) * (diff[i-1] + same[i-1])
        = (k - 1) * (diff[i-1] + diff[i-2])
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's a combinatorics argument.

Let `diff[i, c]` be the number of ways to paint `i` posts according to the rules of the problem statement such that the last fence is painted with color `c`.

We have:

```
diff[i, c] = diff[i - 1, c'] + diff[i - 2, c''], c' != c OR c'' != c
```

For each `c` with which we paint `i`, the previous can either end with a `c' != c` (in which case we don't care what the second previous is), or the second previous can end with a `c'' != c` (in which case we don't care what the previous is), or both.

There are `k - 1` possibilities for `c' != c` and `k - 1` for `c'' != c`. So we can drop `c` from the recurrence and simply write:

```
diff[i] = (k - 1) * (diff[i - 1] + diff[i - 2])
```

Which is what you have.

Comment: small typo in the formula, the second diff[i-1] should be diff[i-2]

Comment: Very educational explanation. Had I taken this question in interview, I probably would do this reasoning:

1) Last 2 posts have same color, therefore last 2 posts cannot be painted same as the last 3 one. (k-1) * diff[n-2]

2) Last 2 posts have different colors. (k-1) * diff[n-1]

Together they  make (k-1) * (diff[n-2] + diff[n - 1])

Comment: To my eyes there is an important missing piece in your proof, and that is how can you prove that diff[i - 1, c'], diff[i - 2, c''] are disjoint sets, otherwise your solutions set might contain duplicates.

Answer (score 7):

The solution involves a detailed explanation. Please do have a look.

```java
public class PaintingFence {

  public static int paintFence(int n, int k) {
    //if there is 0 post then the ways to color it is 0.
    if(n == 0) return 0;

    //if there is one 1 post then the way to color it is k ways.
    if(n == 1) return k;

    /**
     * Consider the first two post.
     * case 1. When both post is of same color
     *    first post can be colored in k ways.
     *    second post has to be colored by same color.
     *    So the way in which the first post can be colored with same color is k * 1.
     *
     * case 2. When both post is of diff color
     *    first post can be colored in k ways.
     *    second post can be colored in k-1 ways.
     *    Hence the ways to color two post different is k * (k - 1)
     */
    int same = k * 1;
    int diff = k * (k -1);

    /**
     * As first 2 posts are already discussed, we will start with the third post.
     *
     * If the first two post are same then to make the third post different, we have
     * k-1 ways. Hence same * (k-1)
     * [same=k, so same * k-1 = k*(k-1) = diff => Remember this.]
     *
     * If the first two posts are different then to make the third different, we also have
     * k - 1 ways. Hence diff * (k-1)
     *
     * So to make third post different color, we have
     *  same * (k-1) + diff * (k-1)
     *  = (same + diff) * (k-1)
     *  = k-1 * (same + diff)
     */
    for(int i=3;i <=n; i++) {
      int prevDiff = diff;
      diff = (same + diff) * (k - 1); //as stated above

      /**
       * to make the third color same, we cannot do that because of constraint that only two
       * posts can be of same color. So in this case, we cannot have to same color so it has to be
       * diff.
       */
      same = prevDiff * 1;
    }

    return same + diff;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(paintFence(2, 4));
    System.out.println(paintFence(3, 2));
  }

}
```